# the process of function zip() python

Tags: python, list

I want to ask a question about `zip()` in python.

Consider the following simple code to demonstrate `zip()`.

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for key, value in zip(a, b):
    print(key + value)
```

I know that the following output is produced:

```
1a
2b
3c
```

where each element in the corresponding lists are concatenated.

As a beginner in Python3, I understand the following about `zip()`:

`zip()` creates a `zip` object, related to OOP that can be shown using `list()`:

```
my_zip = zip(a, b)
print(my_zip)
print(list(my_zip))
>>> <zip object at 0xsomelocation>
>>>[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c')]
```

such that the `zip` object is a list of tuples.

My confusion is in this line from the original block of code, which I don't really understand:

```
for key, value in zip(a, b)
```

My interpretation is that as we are looping through our `zip` object, which has some innate `__next__()` method called on by our `for` loop, we loop through each tuple in turn.

For our first iteration of the loop, we get:

```
('1', 'a')
```

and python assigns `'1'` and `'a'` to our variables `key` and `value` respectively. This is repeated until the end of the list dimensions i.e. 3 times.

Is this the correct interpretation of what is happening in our code?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: Bingo! Yes, you nailed it

Comment: Your question seems to be more about [tuple unpacking](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/) than it is about `zip`.

Comment: @abhiarora done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> such that the zip object is a list of tuples.

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) doesn't return a list of tuples. It returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted. With a single iterable argument, it returns an iterator of 1-tuples. With no arguments, it returns an empty iterator.

> and python assigns '1' and 'a' to our variables key and value respectively. This is repeated until the end of the list dimensions i.e. 3 times.

Yes. Rest of your interpretation is correct.

**BONUS:**

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) should only be used with unequal length inputs when you don’t care about trailing, unmatched values from the longer iterables. If those values are important, use [itertools.zip_longest()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead.